# Не срабатывает код в runtime multiple permission

Tags: android-studio

Есть код:

```
package com.kam.den.runtimepermissions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 10001;
private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 10002;
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE = 10003;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 10004;
// объявляем разрешение, которое нам нужно получить
private static final String READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
private static final String READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String READ_CALL_PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
private static final String READ_CAMERA = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
/////////
private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS = {
        READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        READ_CALL_PHONE,
        READ_CAMERA,
        READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION
};
private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST = 1337;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!canAccessCallPhone() || !canAccessFineLocation() || !canAccessCamera() || !canAccessPhoneNumber()) {requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);}
        else {Toast.makeText(this, "ВСЕ Разрешения есть, можно работать\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }


    }



}


private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    // проверяем разрешение - есть ли оно у нашего приложения
    int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if (requestCode == INITIAL_REQUEST) {
        if (canAccessFineLocation()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessFineLocation получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessFineLocation НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this, " требует разрешение на доступ к GPS", REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        }

        if (canAccessCallPhone()) {

           /* Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:012345"));
            startActivity(callIntent);*/

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCallPhone получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCallPhone НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this, " требует разрешение на доступ к звонкам", REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE);
        }


        if (canAccessCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCamera получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCamera НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this, " требует разрешение на доступ к камере", REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

        if (canAccessPhoneNumber())
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessPhoneNumber получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //  TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NUMBER: " + phoneMgr.getLine1Number(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessPhoneNumber НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к получению номера",REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        //

    }


}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessFineLocation() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCallPhone() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCamera() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessPhoneNumber() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean hasPermission(String perm) { return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(perm)); }

private void requestPermission(String permission, int requestCode)
{
    // запрашиваем разрешение
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
}


private void showPermissionDialog(Context context, String text,  final int RE)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(title + text); //text/" требует разрешение на доступ к положению"

    String positiveText = "Настройки";
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { openAppSettings(RE);  }
    });

    String negativeText = "Выход";
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // display dialog
    dialog.show();
}
private void openAppSettings(int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESS); //REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_CALL_PHONE,REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE); }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_CAMERA,REQUEST_CAMERA); }
}

private void requestApplicationConfig(final String READ_ACCESS, int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_ACCESS)) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Теперь уже разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Пользователь снова не дал нам разрешение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermission(READ_ACCESS, REQUEST_ACCESS);
    }
}
```

}

Собственно вопрос: Где вписывать сам код для которого были получены разрешения? По логике где они находятся в коде, но закоментированы. Если там пишу код, то студия упирается и говорит что для этого кода надо разрешение. Прошу вашей помощи. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается всё сделано правильно. Подчеркивания которые показывает студия, не являются ошибками, а лишь предупреждения, что нужно запрашивать права. Что бы не смушало, добавляем аннотацию @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission"). Вот изменил код вот так и всё прекрасно заработало, ну при наличии разрешений соответственно.

```
package com.kam.den.runtimepermissions;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 10001;
private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 10002;
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE = 10003;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 10004;
// объявляем разрешение, которое нам нужно получить
private static final String READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
private static final String READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String READ_CALL_PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
private static final String READ_CAMERA = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
/////////
private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS = {
        READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        READ_CALL_PHONE,
        READ_CAMERA,
        READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION
};
private static final int INITIAL_REQUEST = 1337;

LocationManager locationManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (!canAccessCallPhone() || !canAccessFineLocation() || !canAccessCamera() || !canAccessPhoneNumber()) {requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, INITIAL_REQUEST);}
        else {Toast.makeText(this, "ВСЕ Разрешения есть, можно работать\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }


    }

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String location = getMyLocation();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




}


private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    // проверяем разрешение - есть ли оно у нашего приложения
    int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if (requestCode == INITIAL_REQUEST) {
        if (canAccessFineLocation())
        {


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessFineLocation получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessFineLocation НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this, " требует разрешение на доступ к GPS", REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        }

        if (canAccessCallPhone()) {

           /* Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0969595858"));
            startActivity(callIntent);*/

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCallPhone получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCallPhone НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this, " требует разрешение на доступ к звонкам", REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE);
        }


        if (canAccessCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCamera получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessCamera НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this, " требует разрешение на доступ к камере", REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

        if (canAccessPhoneNumber())
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessPhoneNumber получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //  TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NUMBER: " + phoneMgr.getLine1Number(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения canAccessPhoneNumber НЕ получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showPermissionDialog(MainActivity.this," требует разрешение на доступ к получению номера",REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        //

    }


}



@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessFineLocation() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCallPhone() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessCamera() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean canAccessPhoneNumber() { return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)); }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean hasPermission(String perm) { return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkSelfPermission(perm)); }

private void requestPermission(String permission, int requestCode)
{
    // запрашиваем разрешение
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
}


private void showPermissionDialog(Context context, String text,  final int RE)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(title + text); //text/" требует разрешение на доступ к положению"

    String positiveText = "Настройки";
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) { openAppSettings(RE);  }
    });

    String negativeText = "Выход";
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // display dialog
    dialog.show();
}
private void openAppSettings(int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACCESS); //REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_CALL_PHONE,REQUEST_READ_CALL_PHONE); }
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) { requestApplicationConfig(READ_CAMERA,REQUEST_CAMERA); }
}

private void requestApplicationConfig(final String READ_ACCESS, int REQUEST_ACCESS)
{
    if (isPermissionGranted(READ_ACCESS)) { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Теперь уже разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Пользователь снова не дал нам разрешение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermission(READ_ACCESS, REQUEST_ACCESS);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private String getMyLocation()
{
    locationManager  = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double latitude = 0,longitude = 0;

    if (location != null)
    {
         latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return  String.valueOf(latitude+"---"+longitude);
}

}
```

А телефонный номер наверное нельзя получить в версиях андроида больше 6. Всегда возвращается null. А в 4 версиях всё работает.